# Throws "Array type 'int [4]' is not assignable" error when trying to call a function on an array

Tags: c++

I wrote a function that the doubles the size of the array

```
int *expand(int ar[], int curr_size) {
    int *new_array = new int[curr_size * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < curr_size; i++)
        new_array[i] = ar[i];

    return new_array;
}
```

When I try to use it

```
int  main(){
    int ar[] = {1,2,3,4};
    ar = expand(ar, 4);
}
```

It throws following error:

> Array type 'int [4]' is not assignable

What is the problem?

---

Comment: The `int ar[]` in the parameter list of `expand` is equivalent to `int* ar` (that is, that `ar` is a pointer, not an array), but the `int ar[]` in `main` is equivalent to `int ar[4]`. Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main()`, `ar` is a fixed sized array. You can't resize it, or assign a pointer to it. All you can do with it is read values from it, and write values into it.

For what you are attempting, you need to allocate `ar`with `new[]`, and then `delete[]` it before assigning a new pointer to it

```
int main(){
    int *ar = new[4]{1,2,3,4};
    int *new_ar = expand(ar, 4);
    delete [] ar;
    ar = new_ar;
    delete [] ar;
}
```

This would be better handled using a `std::vector` instead:

```
#include <vector>
int main(){
    std::vector<int> ar{1,2,3,4};
    ar.resize(ar.size()*2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in c++ do not grow. Their size is set at compile time. Use std::vector instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remy Lebeau absolutely right. 
Your code can be changed like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int *expand(int *ar,int curr_size){
    int *new_array = new int[curr_size*2];
    for (int i = 0; i < curr_size; i++){
        new_array[i] = ar[i];
    }
    delete [] ar;
    return new_array;
}

int main()
{

    int *ar = new int[4]{1,2,3,4};
    for (auto i=0;i<4;i++) {
        cout<<ar[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    ar = expand(ar,4);
    for (auto i=0;i<8;i++) {
        cout<<ar[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```